# How to add two heights property in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add two heights properties came from two different elements? For e.g.

```
var reportHeight = $("#" + loadTo).css("height");
var userCompaniesHeight = $("#UserCompanies").css("height");

// is it possible --> var totalHeight = reportHeight + userCompaniesHeight;
```

TIA

Comment: This is a simple sum; where are you stuck? Did you try?

Comment: @DavidThomas: CSS dimensions are strings with an unit at the end, e.g. `'15px'`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: yes. I know; which can be solved using, among other things, `parseInt()` or `height()`. What I was trying to ask, though I may have been obtuse in some way, is: "what effort was made?" As well as 'Where are you stuck?'

Answer (score 4):

Use `.height()` which returns a plain number in pixels instead of a string containing units.

```
var reportHeight = $("#" + loadTo).height();
var userCompaniesHeight = $("#UserCompanies").height();
var totalHeight = reportHeight + userCompaniesHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `height()` method or else you have the parse out the "px" from what `.css()` returns

```
var totalheight= $("#" + loadTo).height() + $("#UserCompanies").height();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this .. the jQuery CSS() method returns a string so you need to use **parseInt()**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
var reportHeight = parseInt( $("#" + loadTo).css("height"), 10),
    userCompaniesHeight = parseInt( $("#UserCompanies").css("height"), 10),
    totalHeight = reportHeight + userCompaniesHeight;
```

or use the jQuery **height()** method instead as described above